# Combining two lists into a cartesian product in a object of another list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-itertools

I am looking at a way (new to python for about a month now) to make two List[str] objects into a cartesian product that fits into my class.

I have a class like so and two list of strings:

```
# Sample data but could be any strings really
a_strings = ["a", "b"];
b_strings = ["x", "y", "z"];
```

and the class is declared like so:

```
class MyClass(object):

    str_a = None
    str_b = None

    def __init__(self, str_a, str_b):
            
        self.str_a = str_a
            self.str_b = str_b
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```
MyClass("a", "x")
MyClass("a", "y")
MyClass("a", "z")

MyClass("b", "x")
MyClass("b", "y")
MyClass("b", "z")
```

The simple inefficient way is nested for loops like so (which I don't want to do):

```
objects: List[MyClass] = []

for a in a_strings:
    for b in b_strings:
        object.append(MyClass(a, b)
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to do this with:

```
from itertools import product
```

I see how to combine the two lists using itertools above but how do I do it with my object?

Comment: That's not inefficient.  The overhead of the loops is miniscule compared to the cost of allocating all those objects.

Comment: The class an objects are part of a larger class and object creation in a bigger bunch of code but if the the overhead is minimal then I guess it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop method is not particularly inefficient in this case, but if you want to have it as a nice one liner using `product` you can do it like this:

```
[MyClass(*pair) for pair in product(a_strings, b_strings)]
```

Comment: Cool, I do like the nice one liners